# Have different color for first sentence and then the sentence starting after 2 break lines

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Please see the attached screenshot that looks similar to Notes iOS app. But here in this the user would be typing in the menu in the `UITextView` and I want to identify the menu category and have different text color for it. Each menu item would be separated by a single break line. How could I achieve this? Would this be acheivable by using a Regex expression? Any sample code would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: You are completely on the wrong path. Start learning about UITableView.

Comment: This is for when user is entering text in textview. So UITableView would not work here.

Comment: What you are showing in the screenshot would be a perfect use case for a tableView. From the looks of it you will be parsing the text to find each item. A tableView would be more suitable for many reasons, so you might need a custom tableViewRow with a text field in it and add items on return. Think of KVO and your dataSource, it _will_ be simpler, indeed. If you otherwise use the attributed string as-is, I take back every single word ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Julian. The screenshot looks more like a Notes iOS app. I am pretty sure Apple do not use any tableviews in the Notes app. I went on using ((?<=\n\n)|\A).+ regex in the UITextView and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PCRE-Compitible regex should do the work:

```
((?<=\n\n)|\A).+
```

It either matches the first line of your text or a line which follows two newline-characters.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a table view, not a text view. Don't try to force a text view to do something like that. Use a table view.

Comment: Excellent idea to use a table view for a view containing a table :-)

Comment: This is a comment. This makes no attempt to answer the question as asked.

Comment: This is not for displaying only. It is when user is editing and entering text in the UITextView. The UI is similar to the native iOS Notes app and hence tableview will not be used here